# Query how many times a column containing a 'string' appears in a database & table names

Tags: sql, database

I understood this question as I have to find out how many times the string 'word' appears as a column name in the database.

I did it using

```
SELECT 
    table_name, 
    column_name
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE column_name = 'word'
```

But it was marked as incorrect and we were asked to read the question carefully. I am not understanding what it is asking for?

Comment: How many? Check out `count()`.

Comment: Will it be `select count(column_name)` ? I get the same answer, 2 times. But it was wrong.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server MS

Answer (score 1):

The question says "**containing...**" so it means you are not looking for an exact match.

should rather by

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE column_name LIKE '%word%'
```

Comment: Do you know if a View count as a table? Because I got 5 tables with the column names, and one of them is under the Views.

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` returns both tables and views